# Symbolize a finite set by $\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Lets say that $A$ is a set.
I looking for a way to show that $A$ is finite.

I thought about a way and I'd like to know if this way is correct:
$$|A|\in \mathbb{N}$$

or, there is a better (or righter) way to say it's finite, something like: $|A|<n,\ n\in \mathbb{N}$....

Thank you!

Comment: The word "finite" is better. One small technical problem is that many people think of $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of positive integers, in which case $|A|\in \mathbb{N}$ excludes the empty set.

Comment: You could also write $|A|<\infty$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, so If i'm write: $|A|\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\varnothing\}$ is better?  Thank you! (I'm to avoid from words from technical reason).

Comment: It will do, as will your second suggestion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, my second suggestion here at the comments or at the original question?

Comment: In the original question. It is probably simpler to write $|A|\lt \infty$. The only problem with that is that "$\infty$" is not a formal term in any set-theoretic formal language that I know of. But it is certainly understandable.

Comment: When "technical reasons" make your text harder to understand, maybe you need to improve them somehow.

Comment: @GEdgar - This what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is finite if and only if it is equipotent with a proper initial segment of $\Bbb N$. Writing $|A|\in\Bbb N$ should be fine, if in your context $0$ is a natural number. You can instead write $|A|<\aleph_0$, or $|A|<\infty$ if using $\aleph$ might be undesirable.